# Adding a User Control dynamically to a FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

I've created a UserControl and added it to a `FlowLayoutPanel`. The UserControl is being used to allow a user to enter a material, cost and delivery status to the form. When the user has filled it in, I want another UserControl to appear underneath it in the `FlowLayoutPanel`

The UserControl simply generates a string based on the text entered into two `TextBox` controls and the status of two `Checkbox` controls. it also has a property that indicates when the user has filled in enough information. I want to use this property to signal generating a new UserControl.

At the moment I have my first UserControl on the `FlowLayoutPanel`, it is successfully passing the String and `CreateNew` property back.

The problems I am encountering are:

1. How do I monitor to see if `CreateNew` has changed to True?
2. How do I add a control to the form and +1 to the controls name for future referencing
3. Once the new control is added, I need to monitor to see if the new `CreateNew` state changes to repeat the cycle

Can anyone point me in the right direction here, there's a lot of information out there on this, but I can't seem to find anything useful from other's problems/questions.

**UPDATE 1**

Thanks to user Zaggler for the comment, I have now managed to get the control to create a new instance of itself on the `FlowLayoutPanel`. But now I'm faced with a new problem of it only creating one new usercontrol, then it stops.

Here's the code I'm using:

**UserControl Code**

```
Public Class Alv_Product_Order_Control
    Public OutString As String
    Public Event CreateNew()
    Dim CreateNewRaised As Boolean

    Private Sub OutputString(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tbMaterial.TextChanged, tbCost.TextChanged,
        cbDelivered.CheckedChanged, cbOrderPlaced.CheckedChanged

        OutString = "¦¦" & tbMaterial.Text & "¦" & tbCost.Text & "¦"

        If cbOrderPlaced.Checked = True Then
            OutString = OutString & "Yes¦"
        Else
            OutString = OutString & "No¦"
        End If

        If cbDelivered.Checked = True Then
            OutString = OutString & "Yes¦"
        Else
            OutString = OutString & "No¦"
        End If

        If tbCost.Text = "" Or tbMaterial.Text = "" Then
        Else
            If CreateNewRaised = False Then
                RaiseEvent CreateNew() 'Raise the event that's used to signal adding a new control to the layout
                CreateNewRaised = True 'Create A Latched Boolean that cannot change again in the future
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Alv_Product_Order_Control As String
        Get
            Return OutString 'Pass string back to main form
        End Get
    End Property
```

**Main Form Code**

```
Private Sub CreateSecondPOC() Handles POC1.CreateNew
    FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(New Alveare_VB.Alv_Product_Order_Control)
End Sub
```

I'm guessing here that the problem is the `CreateSecondPOC` only handles the event for the the first `POC1`

How do I create a new `Alveare_VB.Alv_Product_Order_Control`, name it as POC2 and also add a handler to handle `POC2.CreateNew` and add another control?

**Edit 2**

I know I've found the answer, but i'd like to look at this memory leak that has been mentioned. I've changed the code supplied in the answer below to this:

```
Private Sub CreateSecondPOC(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles POC1.CreateNew
        Try
            Dim oldPoc = DirectCast(sender, Alveare_VB.Alv_Product_Order_Control)
            RemoveHandler oldPoc.CreateNew, AddressOf CreateSecondPOC
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print(ex.Message)
        End Try

        Dim newPoc As New Alveare_VB.Alv_Product_Order_Control
        AddHandler newPoc.CreateNew, AddressOf CreateSecondPOC
        FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(newPoc)
    End Sub
```

And I get the following error on the "RemoveHandler" line:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' to type 'Alveare_VB.Alv_Product_Order_Control'.

The `CreateNew` event is raised when a textbox is written in, this is getting passed back as the sender I assume? Not really sure where to go with this now.

**Edit 3**

The error was in my `UserControl`, I was sending the incorrect object back (in this case the textbox). I have now changed the `RaiseEvent` to return the `UserControl` as an object. Now all is working correctly.

Comment: Create an event and raise it when you need to. Look into `withevents`...

Comment: @Zaggler Thanks for the direction, I have made some progress, see updated question

Comment: You are welcome, please see comment under Verdolino answer you accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your handler to something like this

```
Private Sub CreateSecondPOC() Handles POC1.CreateNew
    Dim newPoc As New Alveare_VB.Alv_Product_Order_Control
    AddHandler newPoc.CreateNew, AddressOf CreateSecondPOC
    FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(newPoc)
End Sub
```

I'm not sure if you want to keep handling the event, even after it has been populated once, i.e. can it be depopulated, then repopulated, then raise the event again? Maybe you want to lock it once it's populated, but this isn't clear.

You could also keep all your `POC` controls in a container and only create a new one when they are all populated.

**Edit:**

According to comments below, you should remove the event handler when you no longer need it in order to avoid memory leaks. Here is one way

```
Private Sub CreateSecondPOC(sender As Object) Handles POC1.CreateNew
    Dim oldPoc = DirectCast(sender, Alveare_VB.Alv_Product_Order_Control)
    RemoveHandler oldPoc, AddressOf CreateSecondPOC
    Dim newPoc As New Alveare_VB.Alv_Product_Order_Control
    AddHandler newPoc.CreateNew, AddressOf CreateSecondPOC
    FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(newPoc)
End Sub
```

But the *last* `POC` control's event handler would never be unsubscribed. So you could also do something like this when closing the form

```
For Each poc In Me.FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType(Of Alveare_VB.Alv_Product_Order_Control)()
    RemoveHandler poc.CreateNew, AddressOf CreateSecondPOC
Next poc
```

I mentioned above that *You could also keep all your `POC` controls in a container*, which would be a better way to keep track of your controls, instead of using the FlowLayoutPanel as logical container. Just do what works for you and consider removing the handlers.

Comment: I do lock the event, the `CreateNewRaised` Bool stops the event from being raised again, even if its de-populated and re-populated. I'll give this a go, thanks

Comment: One step ahead of me - I should have looked at your code more carefully :)

Comment: @Verdolino one thing to keep in mind is if adding handlers dynamically you need to remove them as well. Consequences can occur if not. For example if not removed the pointer to the object floats round and GC can't find it, therefore memory is not released and causes memory leaks.... With Events handles this for you, just a suggestion.

Comment: @Zaggler agreed, it could be done by passing the sender to the event handler and removing it when it's raised. But why wouldn't the GC handle it after the object handling the events (the class in which `CreateSecondPOC() ` is defined) has gone out of scope?

Comment: If the object gets disposed, then the event that was declared outside for that object is lost, the pointer is gone to that object as it's disposed of.

Comment: Using the new code I get an error "Cant handle the event 'CreateNew' because there is no compatible signature'. This is something to do with the `sender As object`?

Comment: Yes you need to `RaiseEvent.CreateNew(Me)`